Ignore the releasing the specific key combination (shortcut) using a low-level keyboard hook
To intercept the pressed key combination (for example Ctrl+Shift+A) I use this code:
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardMsgProc, hInstance, NULL);

//...

LRESULT WINAPI KeyboardMsgProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *kbdhs = reinterpret_cast<KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam);

    if((kbdhs->vkCode == 0x41 && wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) &&
       (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LCONTROL) & 0x8000) &&
       (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) & 0x8000))
    {
    OutputDebugStringA("Ctrl+Shift+A pressed\r\n");
    }
}

This is simple code and it works.
But I need to intercept key combination release using a low-level keyboard hook. Once again - not pressing the key combination, but releasing the key combination. How can I do that? Any ideas?

Does your hook not get called with WM_KEYUP when the key is released?

RegisterHotKey() does all of that for you already.

@IInspectable but I asked how to do this using a low-level keyboard hook. There no need to intercept WM_HOTKEY. Because the task is to intercept the pressing of the key combination and intercept the release of the keys combination.
To intercept a key combination, it is enough to catch the A-key and check the pressed state of Ctrl key and Shift key. But how can I catch the moment when these three keys are released? It is necessary in one case. It makes no sense in checking the pressed state of Ctrl key and Shift key.

You seem to have this backward: A low-level hook is insanely costly. You only install a low-level hook when there is absolutely positively no other alternative. If you want a (global) hotkey, use the system service designed for hotkeys.

When the key combination captured, make a variable to indicate the start of capturing one release message of the combination keys.

You can get the notification of pressing the key combination according to your question. And as I said in the comment, When the key combination captured, it's time to monitor release messages. Make a variable to indicate the start of capturing one release message of the combination keys. When a release message of the combination keys captured, It's the release of the key combination.
